# Make GNOME Image Viewer not cycle

Tags: gnome, images

I'm using GNOME Image Viewer (ver. 3.38.2) as default, and I navigate lots of data-visualization by using the arrow keys on the keyboard. The data sets could look similar but subtly different, which is difficult to notice. So often I overlook when the image files are cycled, unless I tediously monitor the file names.

It'd be great if there's a configuration that make the image files not cycle. If that's not possible, I'd also appreciate a recommendation of a viewer that don't cycle the files.

Comment: I too am wondering this since eog doesn't have good playlist functionality. I want to use `xargs` but it will not pick images after the first batch of xargs inputs.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat I found `qimgv` which doesn't cycle by default.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I ended up using `find $PWD -type f -iname "**heic" | head -100 | shuf | DISPLAY=:20.0 /usr/libexec/imv/imv  -l -t 4`, as much as I don't like to rely on third party solutions.